# Azure DevOps pipeline error: No builds currently exist in the pipeline definition supplied

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to grab a schema from another artifact build and then build and push the artifact. The error I am getting no builds currently exist in the pipeline definition, I know that is usually from not having a pipeline run on that branch yet. I have run the pipeline and pushed the artifact to the repo on that branch so there is an image already there. The schema was published from the other build. I am not sure why it is not grabbing the artifact. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  jobs:
  - job: Build_Push_Artifact

    steps:
      - task: Docker@2
        inputs:
          containerRegistry: $(azureContainerRegistry)
          command: "login"

      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        inputs:
          source: specific
          project: $(projectId)
          pipeline: $(schemaPublishPipelineId)
          runVersion: latestFromBranch
          runBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)
          artifact: $(schemaArtifact)
          patterns: $(schemaArtifactPattern)
          path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible situation that I can reproduce on my side:

If the build pipeline runs failed in some steps, then even the artifact be published successfully, nothing will be catched.

And please try this simple structure:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '<Project Name>'
    definition: '<Pipeline Name>'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```